# Pattern to match an identifier but not matching reserved keywords

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to design regex that matches an identifier unless it's a reserved keyword.
Here's what I have tried: `(?!{}(?![_a-zA-Z0-9]))[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*` where `{}` gets replaced by something like `if|else|while`. Unfortunately, it can't match *anything* that *begins* with a reserved keyword, so something like `ifa` doesn't pass.
How to design a proper regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part you seem to be missing is the `\b` for word boundaries.  Something along these lines should work:

```
(?!(if|else|while)\b)\b\w+
```